# Turkish visa denied because agency misrepresented my case

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, turkey, pakistani-citizens

I applied for a Turkish visa and was denied. I have a Pakistani passport, but I have traveled to the US and Mauritius.

The problem is that we can't access the embassy directly from Pakistan. We have to go through a courier, and that courier did not forward all my bank statement, despite my insistence. And this, in my opinion, weakened my case.

Now the issue is that I can't get a hold of anyone from the consulate, or the embassy. Has anyone faced this before? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Side question: Do you still have a valid US visa?

Comment: Misrepresentation, and omitting a bank statement that may have had no bearing are different things. Can you post your refusal letter with personal information blanked out?

Comment: This might be a question of local terminology or translation, but a *courier*, i.e. a delivery service, is not the same thing as an *agency*, where someone is working on your behalf. Please clarify which you were using, and if both, which one mishandled the documents.